# insert then and update then in sybase

Tags: sybase

I did a search over the net but I couldnt find my answer

in oracle , if we to specify for the trigere if its insert or update , we write like this :

> create or replace trigger TRG_LOGS
>   after INSERT or update or delete
>      ON TABOE_LOGS
>      FOR EACH ROW
>   DECLARE
>   V_USERNAME VARCHAR2(100);
>   BEGIN
>   
>   if inserting then
>   insert into long_log(NAME) VALUE (:new.NAME)
>   
>   ELSE if UPDATING THEN 
>   insert into long_log(NAME) VALUE (:OLD.NAME)
>   END;
>   END;

Is throwing an error on Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'insert'.

Comment: there something related to deled table and inser table anyone know something about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Sybase, each action is a seperate trigger:

```
create trigger TRG_LOGS_INS on TABOE_LOGS
for INSERT
as
DECLARE @V_USERNAME varchar(100)
BEGIN
    insert into long_log
    select NAME from INSERTED
END
```

....

```
create trigger TRG_LOGS_UPD on TABOE_LOGS
for UPDATE
as
DECLARE @V_USERNAME varchar(100)
BEGIN
    insert into long_log
    select NAME from DELETED
END
```

Not sure if my syntax is exactly right, but should get you pointed in the right direction.  The `INSERTED` table (similar to Oracles `new`) stores the new records on either an insert or update action.  The `DELETED` table (similar to Oracles `old`) stores the old records on either an update or delete action.

More information and examples can be found in the [Sybase T-SQL Users Guide: Triggers](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/X79145.htm)